# Extending Polyline in ArcGIS without intersecting line?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, editing, line, extend

I am trying to extend the ends of each line I have in a seismic survey 2 miles. I have tried using the extend line (Editor) tool but it needs an intersecting line to move to.

Does anyone know how to extend a previously created line a specified distance on both ends without intersecting another line?

Answer (score 4):

The most simple workaround to this problem is to create a buffer around your line, then you convert the buffer into a line ("Feature to line" using both the buffers and the original lines) and finally you run the "extend" tool (Info/advanced licence needed for feature to line, and Editor/standard licence needed for extend, but there are free solutions for the feature to line tool).

EDIT (Thanks Hornbydd for the remarks): you can directly create the line buffer in an edit session (editor toolbar > Editor > Buffer). This tool will work with selected feature only. The extend tool is also available as an editing tool (editor toolbar > Editor > more editing tools > advanced editing)

Comment: This is a nifty way of doing it but its worth mentioning that you would require at least ArcEditor (Standard) license to run the Extend tool

Comment: Ah yes the extend tool on the advance editor tool bar that will work on an ArcView license, nice one!

Comment: @radouxju you would need to merge the initial line feature with the line feature created from the buffer, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this manually you could try moving the end vertices a specified distance. To go right use positive values to go left use negative values. Have a look at how to [move a vertex relative to its current location (delta x,y)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/relative_to_its_current_location_delta_x_y/01m80000002t000000/).

Comment: A similar approach to this would be to use the Continue Feature Tool to extend a line.  Right click and use Direction/Length to extend the line.  Then just Flip the line and extend the other end of the line as well.

Comment: +1 Baltok, there is also another editing option from the content menu called "Length...". This allows you to set the desired length then its up to you to place the vertex that distance away.